# Save Ã© and not é in database

Tags: php, mysql

I've read a lot on the internet about charsets but most of the times people want to save é inside the database instead of Ã©.

I need to save Ã© instead of é.
At the moment strings are saved with é, does anyone know which charset I need to choose so it will be saved as Ã© in my MySQL database?

This is needed to make my offline database compatible with my online database.

Comment: If input data is UTF-8, `latin1_general_ci` or possibly `latin1_swedish_ci` for both connection and storage engine, at a guess (not checked the code points but they are the most common single byte charsets used in MySQL)

Comment: `I need to save Ã© instead of é` - May I know why?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov To be fair, the OP does clearly state `This is needed to make my offline database compatible with my online database.` It's a weird logic but potentially legitimate

Comment: @DaveRandom, no, that's not legitimate. What would be legitimate in this case is to fix the broken database and use correct encoding instead of corrupting the other database.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov OK, fair point - but if that will involve a complete rewrite of the live app which has work-arounds for the incorrect charset in the DB then I can see this being a requirement. Although of course the answer the this question anyway would be to `DESCRIBE` the live table and just look how it is set up

Comment: @DaveRandom, if it requires a rewrite so be it: because if you don't do it now and crap on the other database in a few months time the rewrite will cost you double :-)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov You're right, I'll probably rewrite it first. But to be honest, it looks like all my databases do have "broken encoding" and I have never had any problem with it. I always was able to have the right characters shown on my website, so what is exactly the disadvantage of having Ã© instead of é inside the database?

Comment: @OsiriX PHP treats all strings as byte sequences and ignores charsets. Mysql does not, but is still returning the correct byte sequence to PHP, so as long as you are specifying the correct charset when you send the data to the browser everything will correct itself. The problem inside the database will come when you start trying to match strings with queries. You *might* be able to fix it by converting your VARCHARs to VARBINARYs, then converting them back to VARCHARs with the right charset, and your app will never notice the difference. This is not guaranteed to work though, so test it first!